# Find number of spaces in a string mips assembly

Tags: string, assembly, spaces, mips32

So I have a string in .data. The string is "e8 e r e r c e r g r r r g,".
I want to find the number of spaces in the string. It is stored in $a0, but in a different file and both the file I am writing the method for finding spaces and the file with the string is linked using the "include" feature.

My code isn't working even though I think the idea is right.

my code so far

```
lb $s1, ($a0)
la $s2 ' ' 
li $v0, 0

findNumSpaces:
beq $s1, $zero, printNumSpaces
beq $s1, $s2, isSpace
addi $a0, $a0, 1
lb $s1, ($a0)
j findNumSpaces


isSpace:
addi $v0, $v0, 1
addi $a0, $a0, 1
lb $s1, ($a0)
j findNumSpaces

printNumSpaces:
li $v0, 1
syscall
```

Comment: `la $s2 ' '` is "load address ... space character" ... shouldn't even compile, but MARS has benevolent assembler ignoring slightly wrong syntax and producing *something* out of it. Should be `li $s2, ' '` if you want value 32 in `s2`. Then the `printNumSpaces` will overwrite value in `v0` (where was the count of spaces). Use debugger and single-step over each instruction, to slowly check CPU state after every step, such mistakes should be then obvious (that just before syscall you will suddenly lose the counter value).

Comment: Please don't just update the code in the question; it invalidates the answers.  If you want to add a revised version below, that's still kind of asking a new question in an edit.  Use a debugger to check your fix, and if it works, post it as an *answer*.

Answer (score 0):

1. When it finds a space, it doesn't increment $a0 or load the new value of $s1.
2. It doesn't check for the end of the string, so it will loop forever.

Comment: does the line addi $a0, $a0, 1
lb $s1, ($a0) not do this?

Comment: It does, but when it finds a space it skips over that, and then it doesn’t go back to it, it goes back to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: What about now?